# My logic of insertion sort seems right but does not work

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort

I am trying to implement insertion sort.

```
public int[] insertionSort(int[] a) {

    for(int i=0; i<a.length;i++) {
        int j=i+1;

        while(a[j] < a[i] && j < a.length) {
            swap(a[j],a[i]);
            j--;
            i--;
        }
    }
    return a;
}

public void swap(int a, int b) {
    int temp;
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

Is it not -technically- the same (in terms of output result) as if I was to say j = i-1 and substituting a condition in while loop from j < a.length to j >= 0?

Comment: Does not work in what way? Can you give us sample input/output that isn't working as you expected?

Comment: Apologies, ArrayIndexOutOfBounds. Double checked and can't seem to see any issue with it

Answer (score 2):

You can't swap the values in another method in that way, as the parameters are passing the values, not references to the values.

You're probably better off just not using a separate method for the swap, like this (also had to increment instead of decrement the `i` and `j` values):

```
public int[] insertionSort(int[] a) {
    int temp;

    for(int i=0; i<a.length;i++) {
        int j=i;

        while(j > 0 && a[j-1] > a[j]) {
            temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[j-1];
            a[j-1] = temp;
            j--;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

**Edit**: Had to update again - the conditions in the while loop were in the wrong order so it would look for the next index of the array before checking if it had reached the end of the array.

**Edit 2**: As mentioned in the comments, I'll show how to write a `swap` method that actually works - instead of passing values you'll have to pass the entire array and return it after. I'd still probably recommend doing it the above way, but just for educational purposes:

```
public int[] insertionSort(int[] a) {

    for(int i=0; i<a.length;i++) {
        int j=i;

        while(j > 0 && a[j-1] > a[j]) {
            a = swap(a, j-1, j);
            j--;
        }
    }
    return a;
}


public int[] swap(int[] a, int index1, int index2) {
    int temp = a[index1];
    a[index1] = a[index2];
    a[index2] = temp;
    return a;
}
```

**Edit 3**: Was doing something stupid and hadn't quite given insertion sort. All sorted (excuse the pun) now.

Comment: The code will likely still give a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception due to the j-- and i-- though.

Comment: Didn't check the logic properly after noticing the other problem, I'll address that now!

Comment: he could just pass the array and indexes to the method

Comment: @AmirAfghani Yeah it could be done that way, but you'd have to return the arrays and it just seems kind of pointless - doing it this way keeps it way simpler.

Comment: Have you ran the code? I get an exception with the array { 5, 1, 12, 15 }.

Comment: Wouldn't I want decrement instead of incrementing because I want to swap everytime it is out of order as I am going closer to the beginning of the array (index 0) to make sure smaller value is to the left of the array, hence the j--/i-- rather than j++/i++, if this makes sense.

Comment: Should I pass the value and not the references to the value to swap method because when I use swap method in insertionSort method, I am passing it the integer in that position, hence swap a[j] and a[i].

Comment: @SharkofMirkwood Actually, this is insertion sort, in which case you have to decrement at that point. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

Comment: @SharkofMirkwood This seems closer to bubblesort and doesn't sort all arrays well. When trying { 15, 12, 1, 5 } it did not come out sorted.

Comment: @Simon Well, this is embarrassing... I've updated it now, this is insertion sort and I've tried that array - seems to work fine. Thanks for pointing out my mistake(s)!

Comment: @user2770982 I've fixed it up now, you were right about decrementing and I was thinking of another sorting algorithm... I've put in an explanation of how to do it with the `swap` method working too.

Comment: @SharkofMirkwood You're welcome. Nice pun ;) PS your swap method is generating two errors.

Comment: @Simon Yeah thanks again - couple of silly things there from before, should work now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56852/discussion-between-simon-and-sharkofmirkwood).